# Pass Item Clicked On Dropdown List To Second File

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to pass variable from one file to another file based on item clicked by user from dropdown list.

I would like to use $item in second_file passed from first_file:

First File:

```
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT IMEI FROM trackertable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $item = '<li><a href="http://mydomain/php/second_file.php">' . $row["IMEI"] . '</a></li>';
             echo $item;

             }
        } else {
            echo "IMEI: 0 ";
        }
    ?>
```

Second File:

```
$sql = "SELECT Lat, Long FROM trackertable WHERE IMEI = '$item' ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $_GET to have this information : http://php.net/get

## in the first file:

```
$item = '<li><a href="http://mydomain/php/second_file.php?IMEI=' . htmlentities($row["IMEI"]) . '">' . $row["IMEI"] . '</a></li>';
```

## in the second file :

```
$item = $_GET["IMEI"];
// here test the value to avoid SQL injection
$sql = "SELECT Lat, Long FROM trackertable WHERE IMEI = '$item' ";
```